# Connect a second network powerline adapter to network

Tags: powerline-networking

I bought a network power line adapter and it works well. The unit I bought came with 2 adapters, one plugs into the router and the other goes to the computer.

I wanted to know if I was to purchase another network powerline adapter, can I only get a single adapter, or do I need to get a second one.

In essence can only 1 adapter plugged into the router support 2 other adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 3 adapters shouldn't be a problem. You might notice a speed reduction at the remote end. Use the same brand and model to be sure.
See more at: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/power-network.htm

Comment: Using the same brand is unnecessary. Using the same 'class' is a good idea since I seem to notice slowdowns on mixed networks

Answer (score 1):

This depend on your hardware and this info should be availible in the specifications of that particular device.

Apart from this, i think that most Powerline-Systems are capable of being extended beyond two adapters.

Answer (score 1):

It should work - homeplug scales up to at least 16 adaptors, and have the same network name by default. It'll just be plug and play, unless you need to reset the network name. Follow the instructions on your new unit if it dosen't 'just work'.

At the moment my network has a single homeplug unit at the router, a 4 port homeplug switch and another adaptor connected to a AP on the same network. Homeplug treats the wiring as a 'bus' and any/all units on that circuit talk to each other and share bandwidth.